# Gitfs as backend for salt-stack not working

Tags: git, salt-stack, sal

I am using 2015.8.1 salt-master version and i want to use gitfs as backend but its not working for me.

Please check the below config for the same.

```
fileserver_backend:
  - git

gitfs_provider: pygit2
gitfs_user: salt-stack
gitfs_password: salt-stack-pass
gitfs_insecure_auth: True

gitfs_remotes:
  - http://gitlab.com/url/cm.git:
    - root: salt/salt-states
    - base: master
```

After `git clone http://gitlab.com/url/cm.git` my dir structure look like below.

```
cm/salt/salt-states/top.sls
cm/salt/salt-states/pkg/init.sls
```

I want to run below command which will run state file under repo.

```
salt * state.sls pkg master
```

Is that right command and config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are known issues with gitfs on 2015.8.1. Check the issues list on Github!

Try 2015.5.6, you'll have a better time.